# Facebook graph API fail to load resource bad request 400

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, bad-request

I have the following code on my `controller.js` and works when I request from Facebook Graph 2.4

```
request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/katyperry/posts?"+access_token,true);
```

However this only returns few fields: `message`, `story`, `created_time`, and `id`.

I need some additional more fields: `message`, `picture`, `likes`, `created_time`, `link`, `type`, `comments` and `object_id`.

So I tried the following:

```
request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/katyperry?fields=posts.limit(2){message,picture,likes,created_time,link,type,comments,object_id}"+access_token,true);
```

The last one sent me the error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

I tested both options the request on the Graph API Explorer and it worked properly. How can I get those extra fields? what am I missing?

I am adding the precedent code to show how access_token is builded:

```
var appID ="138429819833219";
var appSecret ="dada0a4d7f7717b0d37fd637d9e1522a";

var accessTokenRq = makeHttpRequest();
var httpString = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+appID+'&client_secret='+appSecret;

accessTokenRq.open("GET",httpString,true);
accessTokenRq.send(null);

var access_token;

accessTokenRq.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (accessTokenRq.readyState == 4) {
    access_token = accessTokenRq.responseText;
    //alert("Hat geklappt - Trabajó :)");

    var request = makeHttpRequest();
    
// the following request works
    request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/katyperry/posts?"+access_token,true);


// next one don't - I checked inspector and access_token contains: 138429819833219|CewVrYOd86ctJ0HTP2X0XAS9m4o
    request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/katyperry?fields=posts.limit(2){message,picture,likes,created_time,link,type,comments,object_id}"+access_token,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is contained in the `access_token` variable? The request

```
/katyperry?fields=posts.limit(2){message,picture,likes,created_time,link,type,comments,object_id}
```

works in the Graph API Explorer, so I guess your `access_token` variable only contains the actual access token, and not the parameter key/value pair.

This

```
request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/katyperry?fields=posts.limit(2){message,picture,likes,created_time,link,type,comments,object_id}&access_token="+access_token,true);
```

should hopefully work then.

Comment: I added the precedent code to original question and checked with inspector the value of access_token, seems to be ok

Comment: Try the request I wrote. Your request misses the &access_token= part before the access token itself

Comment: Tobi, I tried your code, it did't work, throw me: "Invalid OAuth access token signature, OAuthException", 190 In exchange I play around and made it work, it seems it was a syntax error, solution added at the end

Answer (score -1):

The error it was syntax, the right code as follow:

```
request.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/katyperry/posts?limit=2&fields=message,picture,likes,created_time,link,type,comments,object_id&"+access_token,true);
```